# How to prevent directory traversal attack in Apache2 Ubuntu 14?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, directory-traversal

As a system admin role I have to make secure website build in PHP.  Vulnerabilities scanner gives directory traversal attack warning. I google it many websites but didn't found proper solution. I already disable indexing and also put directory deny on /.

Is directory traversal can be prevent by Aapache configuration or by PHP ??

Please guide on this.

Help would be really appreciated.

More detail of question as required.

3rd party already discover vulnerability and download /etc/passwd files through GET method.

here is more in detail.

Vulnerability description
This script is possibly vulnerable to directory traversal attacks.

Directory Traversal is a vulnerability which allows attackers to access
restricted directories and execute commands outside of the web server's root directory. 
This vulnerability affects 
Discovered by: Scripting (Directory_Traversal.script). 
Attack details
URL encoded GET input ofile was set to ../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
File contents found: 
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

**View HTTP headers**

> Request
>  GET removed
>   ofile=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1
>  Referer:
>   removed
>  Cookie: PHPSESSID=7lnb7v198ul8691398urchg833;
>   
> ccity=6cd5165e7bce89782ed37abe9401604a01cb6056s%3A3%3A%22AGR%22%3B;
>   
> lang=13d4e1ed1ec441aca81746dd05751ce248f3fff5s%3A2%3A%22ma%22%3B;
>   
> YII_CSRF_TOKEN=f5e14954e37e2975baa3eec9007f1d89ee8b0302s%3A40%3A%2234cb9e79ba1cafe5dbc69403f245dbcf708adb9b%22%3B
>   Host: removed
>  Connection: Keep-alive
>  Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip,deflate
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.63
>   Safari/537.36
>  Accept: */*

**Response**

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>  Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 08:32:38 GMT
>  Server:
>   Apache
>  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
>  Expires: Thu, 19
>   Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>  Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>  Content-Length: 1348
>   Content-Disposition: inline;
>   filename=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
>  Keep-Alive:
>   timeout=60, max=781
>  Connection: Keep-Alive
>  Content-Type:
>   application/pdf

**Content Of the File**

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
>   daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
>   games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin gnats:x:41:41:Gnats
>   Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:
>   syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false mysql:x:102:106:MySQL
>   Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
>   messagebus:x:103:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
>   landscape:x:104:110::/var/lib/landscape:/bin/false
>   sshd:x:105:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
>   ntp:x:106:114::/home/ntp:/bin/false
>   tpl-nag:x:1001:1002::/home/tpl-

The impact of this vulnerability
By exploiting directory traversal vulnerabilities, attackers step out of the root directory and access files in other directories. As a result, attackers might view restricted files or execute commands, leading to a full compromise of the Web server.

How to fix this vulnerability
Your script should filter metacharacters from user input.

Comment: Your first sentence as a properly formatted user story! What vulnerability scanner are you using?

Comment: We did third party vulnerability scanner service. They did vulnerability scanner through various tools by Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

1) Understand the vulnerability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). I believe you have done this already.

2) Reproduce the vulnerability. Find it yourself according to 1) and your knowledge of what your organization does, or ask the 3rd party who discovered it. If they can't provide at least one concrete example of the vulnerability (e.g.: a URI) ask for your money back :) More than one example would be helpful.

3) You should now have enough information to fix your server. It could be in Apache and/or PHP and/or somewhere else, but there is no way to tell with the information provided in the question. If you still can't fix it at that stage, feel free to ask another question here.

4) Test that whatever you discovered in 2) does not happen anymore after your server changes.

**EDIT** (more info provided)

The 3rd party has actually been kind enough to answer your question: "How to fix this vulnerability Your script should filter metacharacters from user input." Ask them to post their answer here and you can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and information. 

3rd party already discover vulnerability and download /etc/passwd files through GET method. 

Vulnerability description
This script is possibly vulnerable to directory traversal attacks.

Directory Traversal is a vulnerability which allows attackers to access restricted directories and execute commands outside of the web server's root directory.
This vulnerability affects 
Discovered by: Scripting (Directory_Traversal.script). 
Attack details
URL encoded GET input ofile was set to ../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
File contents found:

Comment: More details also there but not allowing big much comment.